# How many permutations have the common minimum in the intersection of $2$ subsets of a set of $1^{st}\ n$ natural numbers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given a set of elements $N=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$and two arbitrary subsets $A\subseteq N$ and $B\subseteq N$, how many of the $n!$ permutations $\pi$ from $N\to N$ satisfy $min(\pi(A))=min(\pi(B))$, where $min(S)$ is the smallest integer in the set of integers $S$, and $\pi(S)$ is the set of integers obtained by applying permutation $\pi$ to each element of $S\ ?$ [e.g: if $A=\{2,3,4\}$ and $\pi=(n,n-1,n-2,\ldots,1)$ then $\pi(A)=\{n-1,n-2,n-3\}$]. Four choices are given as follows :

$i)\ (n−|A\cup B|).|A|.|B|\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ii)\ (|A|^2+|B|^2).n^2\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ iii)\ n!\frac{|A\cap B|}{|A\cup B|}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ iv)\ \frac{|A\cap B|^2}{n\choose|A\cup B|}$

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly? Because choice iv gives fractions when the intersection is of size 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out while walking home from school!

First we pick the numbers to which the set $A\cup B$ is sent be defined(there are $\binom{n}{|A\cup B|} $ to do this

then we need to pick the element of $A\cap B$ that is sent to the minimum element (there are $|A\cap B|$ ways to do this)

Now permute the remaining elements of $A\cup B$ freely in $(|A\cup B|-1)!$ ways

Finally permute the elements not in $A\cup B$ in $(n-A\cup B)!$ ways.

Thus the final answer is $\binom{n}{|A\cup B|}\cdot |A\cap B|\cdot(|A\cup B|-1)!(n-A\cup B)!=n!\frac{|A\cap B|}{|A\cup B|}$

So the correct answer is $iii$

Comment: but the answer given was option $iv)$, which I can not deduce how.

Comment: iv) is incorrect since having an intersection of 1 would give less than 1 almost all the time, while this is not true